# ifstream wont read integers, or anything else for that matter

Tags: c++, file-io

I am using xcode. I compile fine and then once it runs it opens the file successfully and then reads two values but the values do not go into the variable, as such it then skips the for loop and closes the file and returns from main.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

//salesman struct
struct Salesman
{
    char firstname[64];
    char lastname[64];
    char middleinitial[1];
    int averagecents;
    int totalcents;
};

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    //setup variables
    const char* inputFilename = "TheSales.txt";
    int numberPeople = 0, weeksToHandlePerPerson = 0;
    int workweeklength = 5;
    int totalcents = 0;

    //open file

    std::ifstream fileHandle;
    fileHandle.open(inputFilename, std::ios::in | std::ios::app);
    if(!fileHandle)
        perror ( "Stream Failed to open because: " );


    fileHandle >> numberPeople;              <----- does not get value
    fileHandle >> weeksToHandlePerPerson;    <----- does not get value


    //do calculations
    for ( int i = 0; i < numberPeople; ++i )    <---- this gets skipped
    {
        Salesman nextsalesman;
        fileHandle >> nextsalesman.firstname;
        fileHandle >> nextsalesman.middleinitial;
        fileHandle >> nextsalesman.lastname;



        float t1, t2, t3, t4, t5;
        fileHandle >> t1 >> t2 >> t3 >> t4 >> t5;

        nextsalesman.totalcents = 100 * ( t1 + t2 + t3 + t4 + t5 );
        nextsalesman.averagecents = nextsalesman.totalcents / workweeklength;
        totalcents += nextsalesman.totalcents;

        //print calculations calculateNumbers()
        std::cout << "salesman " << i << " total: $" << nextsalesman.totalcents / 100 << "." <<     nextsalesman.totalcents % 100
        << " and average $" << nextsalesman.averagecents / 100 << "." << nextsalesman.averagecents % 100 << std::endl;

        int averagecents = totalcents / ( numberPeople * weeksToHandlePerPerson );


    std::cout << "total for all: " << totalcents / 100 << "." << totalcents % 100 << " and     average for all $" <<
    averagecents / 100 << "." << averagecents % 100 << std::endl;
    }
    fileHandle.close();  <---- this works
    return 0;            <---- then we return main.
}
```

File:

```
3
2
firstName1 A lastName1
20.00 25.00 30.90 40.00 55.50
20.00 25.00 30.90 40.00 55.50
firstname2 B lastName2
30.00 24.00 45.00 67.00 65.50
56.90 87.00 43.50 56.98 55.40
firstName3 C lastName3
62.00 34.50 12.50 34.00 34.90
70.00 80.00 90.00 65.00 39.00
```

where first int is number of employees and second is number of weeks and each week is 5 days.

```
Actual output:   

Expected output:

(fake output but expected form)

salesman1 total: 23424 avg: 3654
salesman2 total: 234   avg: 1654
salesman3 total: 424   avg: 364.

total for all: 5345683  and average for all: 34564564
```

when the program used to work the output was correct.

Comment: What are the contents of "TheSales.txt"?

Comment: Unrelated to your question and you problem, but why use fixed-size arrays for the strings? Why not [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string)?

Comment: Why are you opening the file for reading and using the app flag?

Comment: More related to your problem, I assume that the file actually opens? Because I see a problem with your open-mode, with conflicting flags: The `app` flag is for *writing*.

Comment: app flag does not seem to make a difference it still does not read. I removed it now.

Comment: By the way, when you use `perror` the output might not be correct, because you don't know what happens inside the streams `open` function. If there are some system-calls between the actual "open" system call, and the function exits, then `errno` is no longer reliable.

Comment: The file opens. The debugger told me so.

Comment: this program was originally a mix of c and c++. I am converting it to 100% c++.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on "the debugger told me so"? What do you mean by that? Did you step through the code, line by line, and see that it did not step into the condition and `perror` wasn't called? Can you please edit your question to include the expected *and* actual output?

Comment: Yes I stepped through every line and in the inspector it says: inputFilename const char * "TheSales.txt" 0x0000000100005e48

Comment: there is NO output it skips the for loop because numberOfEmployees is 0 , I will include the expected output.

Comment: Just because some internal members changed value doesn't mean it actually opened the file. If the file doesn't open, you should not only report it but stop what you're doing, there no use in trying to read from a stream if it didn't open properly. Also, when running from an IDE (like Xcode) the programs working directory is often not what one expect to be, it's often *not* where the executable file is, but in the project top directory, and that's where input files have to be.

Comment: my data file is located at:/Users/xxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/name of project/production/debug

Comment: for xcode you HAVE to put the input txt files inside those directories or it can't find them. the old program runs fine with the file inside this directory.

Comment: Shouldn't you have `exit(1);` or `return 1;` after the `perror` call?  **Why are you not checking the result of the `fileHandle >> numberPeople;` statement?!** Why is it that every time there's a stackoverflow question saying "reading from istream doesn't work" the OP never checks their damn read operations? You are coding as though reading never fails **but you know it can fail because that's what's happening!** If the file doesn't open you print an error then just keep going and try reading, and if that fails just keep going, and if that fails just keep going ... check for errors!

Comment: @JonathanWakely wow, take a breath! Perhaps he's come to rely on some implementations [throwing exceptions](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=53984) instead ;-) ?

Comment: @JonathanWakely Sorry I am used to programming in lisp where it just throws you into the debugger when things happen. I'll fix it. Thank you for your comment. It's helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is fine and works for me.

Are you using a text editor that writes out a unicode Byte Order Marker at the start of TheSales.txt? If so, then it will confuse your program.

You can use notepad++ to strip the BOM, as described here:

http://www.larshaendler.com/2015/01/20/remove-bom-with-notepad/

(TextWrangler on OSX might be a good alternative)

Comment: xcode is probably to blame. I'll figure something out and test with a text editor and the terminal. Thanks.